# why are colors dark and unreadable with ssh? cyan in ubuntu = dark blue in ssh, unreadable

Tags: server, ssh, colors

Could anyone help me just making the colors in ssh match the actual server colors?
changing the background just makes other colors unreadable. and is harder to look at as well. Im using ubuntu1804lts. the colors are like this in cmd, powershell, and linuxss4w with ssh.

[image]

Comment: bump? ten more characters